# Lua related query i need solved

Tags: lua, editor

so I have just bought the PIL 3 (programming in Lua 3rd Edition). and have begun reading the eBook. however I am abit confused on the whole interpreter idea. how do I install the editor? I am talking about what do I install and what do I do with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `interpreter` is simple a program that runs the source code usually used to refer to the interactive version of this functionality. In this case the environment you get when you run `lua` from a command prompt.

As to editing lua code there is no dedicated editor, no built-in IDE, no default experience of that sort. You can, and people do, write your code in anything you want so long as it can save it to a file so that you can run it later.

Comment: I recommend Notepad++ - it has Lua (among others) syntax checker.

Comment: I recommend vim. People will also recommend emacs and various other editors. As long as a serious text/programming editor is used the choice doesn't much matter (though personally I would avoid np++ as I find it infuriatingly annoying and impossibly mouse-focused).

Comment: +1 but for someone with background like the OP, my guess is mouse-focused will be a good thing, allowing them to focus (pardon the pun) on the task rather than the keys.

Comment: I should perhaps have said `excessively` instead of `impossibly` my problem is not with allowing the use of the mouse but rather with not making it clear (or necessarily even possible) to do the same things easily without the mouse. But this isn't the place for an editor "war".